# Install conan package without requirements?

Tags: python, c++, package, dependencies, conan

Is there a possibility to install a [conan](https://conan.io/) package without requirements?
I build a metapackage, which only contains some configurations and depends on other binary packages in the requires section.

Now I want to access only the configurations w/out downloading all dependencies, Is there a possibility to do so?

`conan download` downloads a package, but won't install it, e.g. there is no info, where it's downloaded, `conan install` offers the `--json` option for that. It's not configurable with `-s`, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to install a conan package without requirements?

Yes, conan [download](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/misc/download.html) command. It ignores settings.

> conan download downloads a package, but won't install it, e.g. there is no info, where it's downloaded

Not really, it's installed as equal in conan data folder. To obtain any package path, you can run `conan info --paths` (see [info](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/info.html)), but `info` command will download package dependencies.

You have few options:

- Run `conan download`and copy what you need:

```
conan download spdlog/1.8.5@:ff8d59d47be9cd9bef245bc941640efed49089de -r conan-center
cp ${HOME}/.conan/data/spdlog/1.8.5/_/_/package/ff8d59d47be9cd9bef245bc941640efed49089de/licenses/LICENSE new_folder/LICENSE
```

SpdLog requires fmt package, but we don't want to download it too. Thus, we can't run `conan install --paths`

- Run `conan install -g deploy` and copy what you need.

```
conan install spdlog/1.8.5@ -r conan-center -g deploy
cp spdlog/licenses/LICENSE new_folder/LICENSE
```

The deploy generator will download all dependencies, but they will be copied to the current folder too.

Also, partial download was requested some time ago: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/6508, but was denied.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The copy after `download` is not that easy, because I have to use [`CONAN_USE_ALWAYS_SHORT_PATHS`](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/env_vars.html#conan-use-always-short-paths) on Windows to avoid the 260 path limit.
And there might be more than one package with that ID in the future, e.g. I need to filter them by os, compiler, etc.

Comment: I tested the mix of `download` and `info --paths`. I think, this works for now.

Comment: `info --paths` install all requirements too. It's a good option too.

Comment: It didn't download the requirements on my computer. I'm on W10 w/ `conan 1.31.4`.